# Подскажите название библиотеки

Tags: android

Подскажите, пожалуйста, название библиотеки, при помощи которой можно реализовать вот такое перелистывание:

[image: перелистывание фрагментов]

ну или вот такое:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Наверняка есть отдельная библиотека на этот счёт. Если её нет, подскажите, пожалуйста, куда смотреть в сторону реализации.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

это стандартные андроидовские `View`

[ViewPager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) и [TabLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html)

Answer (score 3):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
https://github.com/Devlight/NavigationTabBar

а вообще просмотрите результат поиска на GitHub: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=android+tab&type=

Comment: Крутая библиотека! Не совсем то, что я хотел, но спасибо, очень интересно.

Comment: @ВячеславЧернышов я думал интересует сам эффект))) Если интересует пошаговое - поищите на GitHub Step-By-Step